# source.readList of Parcelable doesn't work over List<String>

Tags: android, parcelable

This  line is red flagged by IDE  :

*`mBook.Color=source.readList(Color,Book.class.getClassLoader());`*

I also changed to

*`mBook.Color=source.readList(Color,String.class.getClassLoader());`*

but still wrong, I thought it's because my code was missing getter & setter for *`color`* field, but after creating them, it's still wrong. I'm sure this is not the way to make the field parceabled but don't know either the correct way to make correct

Book.java :

```
public class Book implements Parcelable {
   private String bookName;
   private int publishTime;
   private static List<String> Color = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"red","blue"});

   public String getBookName() {
      return bookName;
   }

   public static List<String> getColor() {
      return Color;
   }

   public static void setColor(List<String> Color) {
      Book.Color = Color;
   }

   public void setBookName(String bookName) {
      this.bookName = bookName;

   }

   public int getPublishTime() {
      return publishTime;
   }
   public void setPublishTime(int publishTime) {
      this.publishTime = publishTime;
   }

   public static final Parcelable.Creator<Book> CREATOR = new Creator<Book>() {
      public Book createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
         Book mBook = new Book();
         mBook.bookName = source.readString();
         mBook.publishTime = source.readInt();
         mBook.Color =source.readList(Color,Book.class.getClassLoader());
         return mBook;
      }
      public Book[] newArray(int size) {
         return new Book[size];
      }
   };
   @Override
   public int describeContents() {
      return 0;
   }
   @Override
   public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int flags) {
      parcel.writeString(bookName);
      parcel.writeInt(publishTime);
      parcel.writeList(Color);
   }
}
```

Comment: FYI, conventionally your variable names should all start with lowercase. As it is, `Color` is confusing since it appears to be a class, rather than a variable. (you can see the difference in the way the syntax highlighter formats it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `readList` returns a void so that might be what your IDE is complaining about. The solution is the following :

```
 mBook.Color = null;
 source.readList(Color,Book.class.getClassLoader());
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Ah I missed that `source.readList()` is actually *void* because getting used to *non void* `readString()`, `getInt()`, etc. Thanks!

Comment: Alternatively you might want to use `createTypedArrayList(Book.CREATOR)`. Using `readList()` requires that the list that you pass in be the correct size of the parceled list (i.e. you'll need to store the list size as a separate parceled value). `createTypedArrayList(Book.CREATOR)` will return a list you can use to assign the value (i.e. `mBook.color = source.createTypedArrayList(Book.CREATOR)`)

Comment: @kcoppock, technically this answer isn't correct either, I just accepted it as it pointed me out that I simply assigned void method which is not returning a value (I found it funny since `readInt()` is non void, but `readList()` is). The wrong part is that `Book.class.getClassLoader()` gives wrong run time type  as should be `String.class.getClassLoader()`. I also avoided `createTypedArrayList` as the list's signature type is simply String and not a custome class. Ah android is confusing anyway, let's shopping!.